# How does the Zombie Dogs rune Life Link work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

[image]

I'm uncertain on some of the details of Life Link, specifically:

- Is it 10% damage reduction, or 10% damage reduction for each dog?
- How is the absorbed damaged divided amongst the dogs? (evenly, one chosen at random, et cetera)
- If the dogs don't have enough health left to absorb the full 10% damage, will the surplus damage be dealt to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The damage you take is spread out evenly throughout all of your dogs , yes the surplus will be dealt to you

Comment: How do you know thiS? Do you have a source, or did you perform in-game testing?

Comment: that makes sense... but links would be appreciated